# I can't see the hdri background in my final render and render view in the viewport

Tags: hdri

i'm pretty new to blender and I have a problem. Every time I import an HDRI image, the lightning changes, but not in the right way. the background color changes but the background itself doesn't change, I'm using cycles. I impoort my HDRI images by setting the base color of the world to image texture, I don't know if there is another way and if I should use it that way. The answer is probably very simple but I just can't seem to find a solution to it. Thanks in advance!

Someone asked for the node setup of the world so here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5i8C.jpg

[image: my world settings and the rendered view in cycles]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your node setup ?

Comment: Here it is https://imgur.com/a/X6P9Y4D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you used Image texture node for the hdri? You shouldnt.  Add "Enviromental texture" node instead.

Comment: Oh haha that was dumb of me, it works now, thanks!

Comment: @RAVI np, thats some easy mistake